# cursor.find() callbacks not returning in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am returning results from a collection with the second result dependent on the first. So, I find resultA, and resultB has to be anything not equal to result A.

My console.log statement shows the data that I want, however, when I return it, nothing shows up in my handlebars template. Nothing returns even if I JSON.stringify it.

```
myCollection.find({}, {limit:1, skip: _.random(minimum, maximum)}).forEach(function(a){

        myCollection.find({'': {$ne: a._id}}, {limit:1}).forEach(function(b){

            console.log({resultA: a, resultB: b})

            return {resultA: a, resultB: b};        

        });

    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Now I have tried using deps.autorun just incase the collections aren't ready (which they are because console.log always works)

```
Template.votes.helpers({
twoItems: function(){
    var minimum = 0;
    Deps.autorun(function(){
        var maximum = (Items.find().fetch().length) - 1;

        if (maximum){
            var itemA = Items.find({}, {limit:1, skip: _.random(minimum, maximum)}).fetch()[0];
        }

        if(itemA){
            console.log(itemA);
            var itemB = Items.find({'': {$ne: itemA._id}}, {limit:1}).fetch()[0];   
        }

        if (itemB) {
            data = {itemA:itemA, itemB:itemB};
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
    });
},});
```

with a simple template:

```
<template name="votes">
<p>Test</p>
<hr>
{{twoItems}}
<hr></template>
```

At the very least it should return Object but nothing. Console.log always returns the correct data but nothing shows up in the rendered handlebars templates.

Edit: I ended up having to use the following:

```
    twoItems: function(){
    var minimum = 0;
    var maximum = (Items.find().fetch().length) - 1;
    var itemA = Items.find({}, {limit:1, skip: _.random(minimum, maximum)}).forEach(function(a){
        Session.set('itemAid', a._id);  
    });

    var itemA = Items.find({'_id': Session.get('itemAid')}).fetch()[0];
    var itemB = Items.find({'_id': {$ne: Session.get('itemAid')}}, {limit:1,skip: _.random(minimum, maximum - 1)}).fetch()[0];

    return {itemA: itemA, itemB: itemB};
},
```

I still don't know why call backs aren't able to return anything. In the docs it says

> If you include a callback function as the last argument [In a Meteor.Call] (which can't be an argument to the method, since functions aren't serializable), the method will run asynchronously: it will return nothing in particular and will not throw an exception.

So I'm assuming that since a collection operation is a meteor call as well, then that is why the returns are being ignored.

Comment: post the code of handlebars

Comment: Right, the error is most likely in Handlebars.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I just have {{twoItems}} in the handlebars. I also had tried {{#each twoItems}}{{this}}{{/each}}. The odd thing however, is that if I place the return statement _outside_ of the forEach (or map) call back, then it returns and the sample data shows up. But nothing inside the find callbacks get returned. But I know that the code within the callback gets executed because all my console.log() statements get executed inside the foreach and/or map callbacks.

Comment: hm... Is it because the return is going somewhere other than handlebars?

Comment: The quote you include on Meteor.call() is irrelevant.  Meteor.call() is a function that calls a meteor method.  You are not using Meteor.call() or any meteor methods.

Answer (score 1):

I can duplicate this problem by wrapping some working template helpers I have in Deps.autorun and it is as you say - console log shows it ran but nothing in the browser.

A more standard way to write this might be:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  var itemA, itemB;
  var minimum = 0;
  var maximum = (Items.find().fetch().length) - 1;

  if (maximum){
    itemA = Items.findOne({}, {skip: _.random(minimum, maximum)});
  }

  if(itemA){
    console.log(itemA);
    itemB = Items.findOne({ _id: {$ne: itemA._id}});   
  }

  if (itemB) {
    var data = {itemA:itemA, itemB:itemB};
    console.log(data);
    Session.set( "twoItems", data);
  }
});

Template.votes.helpers({
  twoItems: function(){
    return Session.get( "twoItems" );
  }
});
```

I expect this will show "[object, object]" in your browser when run but I think you are expecting that and will change the template call once something is being returned.

Also in your template your last `<hr>` should be `</hr>`.

Comment: Thanks it seems to work w/ session setting. Do you have any ideas about where return statements go in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the inner workings that well.  The template system already looks for reactivity in its inputs and by nesting a second set of dependencies inside that I expect it just gives up.  You code may also have worked and remained reactive by just removing the autorun code.  I was less sure of that though

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. It complained about not being able to access any of the collections outside if the helper. But I did end up using sessions. Let me post that as well.

Comment: I have edited my original message. Please check if that makes sense.